# The values that are being printed are only of array[0]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
function DisplayOE(){
$link = mysqli_connect('local','kw','pass'); //Creates a connection
if(!$link){die(' Could not connect: '.mysql_error());}
mysqli_select_db($link,'kvw') or die(mysqli_error());
$rows = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM CreateOE");
$oe = mysqli_fetch_array($rows);
//$OEquestions = 

    return $oe;
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

//$result = DisplayOE();

print_r(array_values(DisplayOE()));

Hello everyone, I have a table in phpmyadmin. I am trying to return the data from the whole table as an array. Whenever I try to test it it only prints out all the values of [0] => Array. So it only prints out the values of 1 row. How can I make it print out all the rows, so I know it is working properly?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array fetches only one row at a time. have a look at [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Comment: Thanks Ill check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {

}
```